# How to create responsive sticky navigation like this link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

http://preview.themeforest.net/item/flatsome-multipurpose-responsive-woocommerce-theme/full_screen_preview/5484319

that when you scroll up certain px goes screen off and after again certain px scroll up and again visible on the top as a fixed navigation bar

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow! Please see the [Tour], read [ask] and how to create a [mcve]. Post some code of what you've tried. As it stands, your question is too broad for us to help you effectively. We'll help you with a specific problem, but won't write it for you. That's the beauty of web: you want to see how it's done, inspect the page. The code is already there for you...

Answer (score -1):

HTML

```
<nav id="nav">NAV BAR</nav>
```

CSS

```
body{
  margin:0;
  height:200vh;
}
#nav{
  width:100vw;
  height:10vh;
  background-color:black;
  color:white;
  text-align:center;
  line-height:10vh;
}
```

JS

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
  var hiding = false;
  var height = $('#nav').outerHeight();//the certain pixel
  $(document).scroll(function(){
    var scroll = $(document).scrollTop();
    if (scroll >height){
     $('#nav').css({'position':'fixed','top':'0','left':'0'}, 300);
      if(hiding == false){
      $('#nav').css('display','none');
      $('#nav').slideDown();
        hiding= true;
      } } else if(scroll <height) {
        $('#nav').css('position','relative');
        hiding = false;
      }
  });
});
```

[**Live Demo**](http://cr8code.co/editor.php?workid=9e694b497e4eab9934860948c4329317)

Comment: Please tell me why did you downvote then I could fix myself.